# Error while trying to install pyttsx3 library

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pyttsx

I was trying to install pyttsx3 using pip on windows 10 when I get this error plus a very fat red code that I included

````
Collecting comtypes; platform_system == "Windows"
  Using cached comtypes-1.1.7.zip (180 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for comtypes, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: comtypes, pyttsx3
    Running setup.py install for comtypes ... error```


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRdBx.png
````

Comment: Try installing the package wheel using pip. https://pypi.org/project/wheel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating setup tools and then try again the install:

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install pyttsx3
```

If it doesn't solve your issue you can also try to specify the version for pyttsx3

```
pip install -U pyttsx3==2.71
```

If this doesn't work also, try installing it directly from the official github repo:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3
```

If still doesn't work, consider changing your python version.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your issue

```
pip install wheel
```

and then,

```
pip install pyttsx3
```